# Angular testing stub returning variable times out test

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

So I have a stub for a service in a unit test where I need to change a returned value for different tests. I've tried using a spy to capture and return the needed value but that hasn't worked. Currently I have the relavent function returning a variable declared earlier, however, this just makes every test timeout, as though a value is never returned.

```
let schoolIn = false
const calandarServiceStub = {

  getSchedule(a) {
    return Promise.resolve()
  },
  // currentClass(a){
  //    return 'cu'
  // },
  next(a) {
    return 'nextu!'
  },
  convertTime(a, b) {
    return 650
  },
  isSchoolIn(a, b) {
    return schoolIn
  },
  needsInc(a, b) {
    return false
  },
  endsIn(a) {
    return 'endseen'
  }
}
```

And the error

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
    at http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?916005cc407925f4764668d61d04888d59258f5d:1973:23 [ProxyZone]
    at ProxyZoneSpec.Array.concat.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?debf1c3289163cfbc2c419b8e0e217abd44684a5:79544:39) [ProxyZone]
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?165d95334de0fc3588419d6d62f0ed66f90a6ad5:1552:36) [ProxyZone]
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?165d95334de0fc3588419d6d62f0ed66f90a6ad5:1320:47) [<root> => ProxyZone]
    at ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?165d95334de0fc3588419d6d62f0ed66f90a6ad5:1615:38) [<root>]
    at timer (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?165d95334de0fc3588419d6d62f0ed66f90a6ad5:2695:29) [<root>]
```

When I write it like this:

```
  isSchoolIn(a, b) {
    return true
  },
```

It all works fine, except for when I need that value to be false.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `(calandarServiceStub.getSchedule as Spy).and.returnValue(Observable.of(true))`

the `Observable.of`returns right away!

This can be done in every test where it is nessesary, or in a beforeEach if it applies to all tests

### Update

I realise my answer was insufficient.
So i will try and do better:

I would mock the calls in the providers. This way I don't have to make a stub, og use `spy.and.callFake`

```
describe('Service', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: calandarService,
          useValue: {
            getSchedule: _ => Observable.of(false),
          },
        },
      ],
    });
  });

  beforeEach(()=>{
    ...
  });
```

});

if you wish to spy on al element you can still do so: `const spy =`spyon(serivce,'getSchedule');`

and then : `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);`

Comment: So this would go in each test or the beforeEach of a section?

Comment: You can du both